# Android actionbar dropdown navigation with fragments, change item to previous when popping backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

How do I in a correct way change the menu item back to the previous when I pop the back stack?

In onCreate I have the following to create the menu:

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
itemList.add(getString(R.string.planning_shift));
itemList.add(getString(R.string.planning_personal));
itemList.add(getString(R.string.planning_line_statistics));
ArrayAdapter<String> aAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, itemList);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(aAdpt, this);
```

With this I also have:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        switch (itemPosition) {
        case 0:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new ActivityPlanningFragment())
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new MyActivityPlanningFragment())
                    .addToBackStack("MyActivityPlanningFragment").commit();
            break;
        case 2: 
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new LineSearchFragment())
                    .addToBackStack("LineSearchFragment").commit();
            break;
        }
}
```

When I open the app I have the first fragment loaded, position 0. Then If I select position 1 and after 2 in the dropdown navigation. Then pop the back stack. How to I get the drop down to show the correct item?

If I use `actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(item);` it counts as I clicked an item and is added again instead. Suggestions?

Comment: Note that `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST)` is deprecated as of Android 5.0.

Comment: I know, I only target a specific group of devices. And its not a public app.